# Can I configure network cards with iDRAC?

Tags: dell, drac

We have a Dell R720 server. Can we use iDRAC to configure the network interfaces of the server? We have installed CentOS 6.5 on it.

Comment: I don't see any option in my iDRAC for configuring the NIC for the OS running on the server. You can configure the iDRAC NIC settings but I don't see how you can configure the OS NIC settings from the iDRAC.

Comment: Can you explain why/how you're in this situation?

Answer (score 4):

You ought to be able to get console access through your iDRAC, if memory serves.  Do that, log in as if you were seated in front of the machine, and configure the NICs accordingly (edit `/etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-eth0` or as appropriate, `service network restart`).

Answer (score 1):

I work for Dell.  Yes you can use the iDRAC to configure network interface settings.  How you do that depends on which settings you need to configure.  For pre-OS or Hardware settings (ones that you would set through F2 at boot like iSCSI, FCoE, partitioning) you can use the iDRAC WSMAN interface or you can also use the virtual console (via iDRAC web interface) for remote KVM then reboot the system and press the appropriate keys at boot to access configuration tools.

Linux shell scripts to configure NIC using WSMan.
http://media.community.dell.com/en/dtc/attach/nic.zip

For additional information and other scripts see
http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/1981.scripting-the-dell-lifecycle-controller.aspx

For OS level network settings (IP, DNS, routing) you need to use the virtual console (via iDRAC web interface) for KVM access to the server.  Then use the OS tools to configure these settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH to log in via the iDrac IP address. You might need to add SSH privileges for the iDrac user account in the iDrac web interface.

After logging in with SSH, just type `connect` and you will be connected to the serial console, after that you can log in with the OS credentials and proceed with configuration.